# Is it Possible to Boot a New OS While Currently Running?

Tags: boot, mount

Let's assume I'm running CentOS (actually, if this question only applies to certain distros, which ones?). I have another drive (that I can boot from - it's got everything installed) mounted into my file tree.

Is it possible to just boot from that drive without restarting or anything? E.g. would there be something like `bootfrom /stuff/miscmounteddrive/` or some other such command?

Comment: What exactly does it mean to "boot without restarting"?

Comment: @cjm Well, I know on Windows, if you want to boot from a different disk, you need to shutdown/restart the computer to do so. I was wondering if it's possible to tell Linux to boot without having to restart the computer and select the disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the help of virtualization layer, like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). Alternatively, [User-mode Linux](http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/) might do the trick too.

Comment: Virtualization layer... like VMware? If so, how might I go about doing this? Any pages you can point me to?

Comment: Yes, VMWare and VirtualBox are both providing virtualization solutions. Here is Centos page about VirtualBox installation: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Virtualization/VirtualBox

Comment: IIUC, you're talking about booting the secondary OS into a VM.   I think the OP wants to *switch* - 'leave' the primary, and have the secondary running as the new primary.   I'm not sure why.  Hypervisors might be worth mentioning.

Comment: @hunter2 Given the fact he accepted my answer, I guess the OP was looking for that kind of approach. In any case, VirtualBox is an hypervisor too (albeit type 2). It is far less intrusive that type 1 hypervisors as it doesn't require to reinstall everything in order to be able to boot an alternative OS.